# Delete button after certain class and add it back

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML as

```
<ul class="restListings"></ul>
```

I am adding some data dynamically to the ul as shown

```
var divhtml = $('<sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub>');
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    divhtml.append('<li><h6>' + response[i].name + '</h6><p>' + response[i].address + '</p></li>');
}
```

Once this is done i am creating a new button and want to add it after the ul tag

```
var $newbutton = $('<input/>').attr({ 
    type: 'button', 
    location: locationname,
    name: 'btn1', 
    class: 'btn btn-success  testclass', 
    value:locationname
});
```

I need to do this  way .

1. If any button by name testclass is there after class restListings delete it and then add these new button after the class restListings

I tried this way

```
$('.restListings').append($newbutton);
```

but this is being added to middle of `ul` tag

When i tried with `insertAfter` this button is being added multiple times .

This is coming this way

```
<ul class="restListings">
   <sub class="sub">
      Your Favorite Restaurant<br>
      <li>
         <h6>Swaghat</h6>
         <p>MadhaPur , Near Policstation,Hyderabad</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <h6>Swaghat</h6>
         <p>MadhaPur , Near Policstation,Hyderabad</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <h6>Swaghat</h6>
         <p>MadhaPur , Near Policstation,Hyderabad</p>
      </li>
   </sub>
   <input type="button" location="LocationX" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success  testclass" value="LocationX">
</ul>
```

Comment: You are appending `li` to `sub` surely invalid html. Also you need to specify where are you appending `divhtml`?

Comment: *"If any button by name testclass is there after class restListings delete it"*: According to your sample `HTML` - **1)** there are no button with name `testclass `, buttons name is `btn1`. **2)** If you meant button having class `testclass`, then there are no such buttons **after** `.restListings`, it is **inside** it. Maybe you want to totaly rephrase your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$('.restListings').find('.testclass').remove();
```

Comment: Thannks , then after this i need to use insertAfter  know ??

Comment: @PreethiJain: You can use append after this if there are no other elements in it.

Comment: I have edited my question with the insertAfter option .

Comment: @PreethiJain: where exactly you want it be added. if it shoul be after sub then use `$('.restListings').append($newbutton);`

Comment: I want to add new button after </ul> tag .

Comment: @PreethiJain: but input is inside ul tag. should not new button be added there??